# Add paragraph tags to post content in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, paragraphs

I'm getting some pages with the get_pages function and echoing the page content like: `$page->post_content`, but contrary to `the_content()`, this way wordpress wont add p tags automatically, is there any way to add them here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`wpautop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) function.

Answer (score 27):

You should use `<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); ?>`

Answer (score 3):

Jose Carlos' answer is actually the better approach. Out of the box, 'the_content' filter is loaded with the following actions:

- capital_P_dangit
- wptexturize
- convert_smilies
- convert_chars
- wpautop
- shortcode_unautop
- prepend_attachment

So you can see that there's a lot more intelligence behind this filter. If you're positive that you don't need the other stuff (are you 100% sure you'll never have shortcode or smilies in your text?) then go ahead and use wpautop(), but you may regret it later on.

Answer (score -4):

This might be what you're looking for, isn't it?

```
<?php

// Get WordPress pages
$wp_pages = get_pages();

foreach ($wp_pages as $wp_page)
{
    echo '<p>';
    echo $wp_page->post_content;
    echo '</p>';
}
```